# populate a html list control using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, html, vb.net

I have a list defined like so:

```
<ul id="myList" class='myClass'>
    <li class="myItemClass">Item 1</li>
    <li class="myItemClass">Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

using .NET how can I add items to the list dynamically? I also need to specify the class name on each new item

Comment: Using the asp:BulletedList is not an option?

Answer (score 15):

you can even use that HTML, adding runat="server" you will be able to treat it as a HTMLControl no mater what control it is, I do this often with div's

```
<ul id="myList" runat="server" class="myClass">
    <li class="myItemClass">Item 1</li>
    <li class="myItemClass">Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

then you get that HTMLControl and play with it

```
HtmlGenericControl li;

for (int x = 3; x <= 10; x++)
{
    li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
    li.Attributes.Add("class", "myItemClass");
    li.InnerText = "Item " + x;

    myList.Controls.Add(li);
}
```

you will end up with:

```
    <ul id="myList" runat="server" class="myClass">
        <li class="myItemClass">Item 1</li>
        <li class="myItemClass">Item 2</li>
        <li class="myItemClass">Item 3</li>
        <li class="myItemClass">Item 4</li>
        <li class="myItemClass">Item 5</li>
        <li class="myItemClass">Item 6</li>
        <li class="myItemClass">Item 7</li>
        <li class="myItemClass">Item 8</li>
        <li class="myItemClass">Item 9</li>
        <li class="myItemClass">Item 10</li>            
    </ul>
```

of course that you can use an ordered or unorderer list, they also below to the ASP.NET Web Controls.

```
<asp:BulletedList runat="server" ...
```

Comment: I am trying to employ this technique. But I get null reference exception on using "mylist.something" in user-control's code-behind. Can some one please help.

Answer (score 5):

You could use asp:BulletedList like

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="MyList1" CssClass="MyClass" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem Text="Item1" class="MyClass" />
</asp:BulletedList>
```

Add add code like

```
ListItem item = new ListItem("Item2");
item.Attributes.Add("class", "MyClass");
MyList1.Items.Add(item);
```

Or if for some specific reason you need to use the ul tag then you can add a runat="server" to it. E.g.

```
<ul id="MyList2" class="MyClass" runat="server">
  <li class="MyClass">Item1</li>
</ul>
```

With code like

```
HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
li.Attributes.Add("class", "MyClass");
li.InnerText = "Item2";
MyList2.Controls.Add(li);
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way you can solve this problem is by using the asp repeater control

```
<ul id="myList" class='myClass'>
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterMyList" Runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
  <li class="myItemClass">
   <%# Eval("Item") %>
  </li>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

[Edit] - Do remember to set the datasource on repeaterMyList and call databind on the repeater control in the codebehind.

```
repeaterMyList.DataSource = someDataTable;
repeaterMyList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that there is a valid reason for you not to use the BulletedList webserver control. Anyway, this is an interesting programming exercise that illustrates the internals of the Htmlservercontrol architecture and how they map to simple HTML tags.

The HTML `ul` and `li` tags are not directly mapped as HTMLServercontrols. This means that even if you add a `runat="server"` attribute to the list, it's contents will not be directly accessible as listitems.

However, all controls not directly mapped as Html server controls are accessible via the `HtmlGenericControl` class. This makes it possible to create and modify such controls dynamically.

The solution, therefore, is twofold:

- Make the unordered list `runat="server"` so that you can access it in server-side code. Also, you should make the existing items in the list `runat="server"`, else they will be only be accessible as an `LiteralControl` that contains the first two listitems as plain text.
- In code, access the contents of the list and add a new HtmlGenericControl of type "li" to it.

**The following (bare-bones simple) page demonstrates this procedure :**

---

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>

<script runat="server">

  Private Shared addedItems As List(Of HtmlGenericControl)

  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
      'On first load, instantiate the List.
      addedItems = New List(Of HtmlGenericControl)
    End If
  End Sub

  Protected Sub btn1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'Add the previously created items to the UL list.
    'This step is necessary because
    '...the previously added items are lost on postback.
    For i As Integer = 0 To addedItems.Count - 1
      myList.Controls.Add(addedItems.Item(i))
    Next

    'Get the existing no. of items in the list
    Dim count As Integer = myList.Controls.Count

    'Create a new list item based on input in textbox.
    Dim li As HtmlGenericControl = CreateBulletItem()

    'Add the new list item at the end of the BulletedList.
    myList.Controls.AddAt(count, li)
    'Also add this newly created list item to the generic list.
    addedItems.Add(li)
  End Sub

  Private Function CreateBulletItem() As HtmlGenericControl
    Dim li As New HtmlGenericControl("li")
    li.InnerText = txtNewItem.Value
    li.Attributes("class") = "myItemClass"

    Return li
  End Function
</script>

<html>
<head runat="server">
  <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <ul id="myList" class='myClass' runat="server">
        <li runat="server" class="myItemClass">Item 1</li>
        <li runat="server" class="myItemClass">Item 2</li>
      </ul>
      <input type="text" id="txtNewItem" runat="server" />
      <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btn1_Click" />
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I am new to .net may I ask why do you create addedItems = New List(Of HtmlGenericControl) on page load? I can't see this list is 'binded' to any control, is it? Why do you add items from this list to ul? Sorry if it's a newby question.

Comment: @dasha: Because the dynamically created listitems are not persisted in memory or ViewState. I needed to store the newly created listitems somewhere so that I could add them back to the UL. Also, I needed to make the "addedItems" variable Shared to be able to access it upon postback.

Comment: I have added explanatory comments to the code. Hope this helps. :-)