# Null reference exception on calling server side control from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, htmlgenericcontrol

I have exactly the same problem mentioned in [populate a html list control using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924592/populate-a-html-list-control-using-net)

I have kept

```
<ul id="myList" runat="server" class="myClass">
</ul>
```

in ascx file and trying to fill it dynamically from user-control's code behind.

When I try to employ the solution:

```
HtmlGenericControl li;

for (int x = 3; x <= 10; x++)
{
    li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
    li.Attributes.Add("class", "myItemClass");
    li.InnerText = "Item " + x;

    myList.Controls.Add(li);
}
```

I get null reference exception at myList.Controls. Do I need to initialize it somewhere?

Comment: Are you sure `myList.Controls` is initialized? Check stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: if the `myList` is null, is means that you do not have it on page, or you do not have the page (eg you call it with custom ajax as static)

Comment: I am just trying to access this on PageLoad. Is it not right?

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me.

```
<ul id="myList" runat="server" class="myClass">
</ul>

HtmlGenericControl li;

for (int x = 3; x <= 10; x++)
{
    li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
    li.Attributes.Add("class", "myItemClass");
    li.InnerText = "Item " + x;

    myList.Controls.Add(li);
}
```

Comment: I had clientidmode set to inherit which was changing the id. Keeping it static has solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had clientidmode set to inherit which was changing the id. Keeping it static has solved the problem